# Laravel: update composer package without ssh

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have live laravel project facing errors with [pecee/simple-router](https://packagist.org/packages/pecee/simple-router) I am running PHP 7.2 on my server and have pecee/simple-router 3.7.0 installed which requires php 5.4.0. I want to update it to latest version 4.2.0.6 but I don't have access to ssh. I only have ftp.

how can I so

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/site_name/sub_domains/sign.site_name.com/vendor/pecee/simple-router/src/Pecee/SimpleRouter/SimpleRouter.php(52): Pecee\SimpleRouter\Router->routeRequest()
#1 /home/site_name/sub_domains/sign.site_name.com/src/Application.php(97): Pecee\SimpleRouter\SimpleRouter::start()
#2 /home/site_name/sub_domains/sign.site_name.com/index.php(11): Simcify\Application->route()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/site_name/sub_domains/sign.site_name.com/vendor/pecee/simple-router/src/Pecee/SimpleRouter/Router.php on line 287
```

Comment: Run it locally and then upload the vendor folder.

Comment: Please share more details. The given error message does not look like something that Composer should print

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write your command in php and call that file. Like this

```
<?php exec('composer update pecee/simple-router') ?>
```

or make a laravel command and write the same command there.